# How to get single value in inside object stored datatype as json in database codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is My JSON object. Its stored in database as datatype json. so what is i want i want to get **block_id** from this object (note: this object saved in the database as JSON datatype).

```
[{"class": null, "divid": 1545294471098, "style": "position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 7px;", "content": "<span>-</span>", "block_id": 1603, "dataset_id": "", "ondblclick": null, "element_name": "Chart", "bock_type_name": "Chart"}]
```

how to do this accessing method inside CodeIgniter model and return that value to controller ?

Comment: how can you get that data?
is that a json array?

Comment: public function check_block($id){
        $this->db->select('data');
        $this->db->from('table');
        $this->db->where('id', 1);
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $block = $query->result_array();
        $idd = '';
        foreach ($block as $key => $value) {
            $idd[] = $value->block_id;
        }

    }

Comment: i'm written this way to get data from database

Comment: is it possible to get javascript function value/id inside vue function? if it is possible how to do that?